# probability, need help with identifying domain limits when transforming variables (X,Y) to (U,V)

Tags: probability

lets say I have $X\sim EXP(1)$ and $Y\sim EXP(2)$ and they are independent.
and I want to transform to $(X,X+Y)=(U,V)$

The jacobian is $1$, so $f_{u,v}(u,v)=2e^u e^{-2v}$

and now I want to get $f_v$ by integrating $f_{u,v}$- what are the limits? my intuition says 0 to $\infty$ but that wont converge.

(I know I can solve it by convolving the two densities, but I want to know both methods...)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(u,v)=(x,x+y)$, then $(x,y)=(u,v-u)$ hence $[x\gt0,y\gt0]$ if and only if $[v\gt u\gt0]$.
Since $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2\mathrm e^{-x-2y}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0,y\gt0}$ and $x+2y=2v-u$, the density $f_{U,V}:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R_+$ can be the function defined by 
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v)=2\mathrm e^{u-2v}\mathbf 1_{v\gt u\gt0},
$$ 
for every $(u,v)$ in $\mathbb R^2$. In particular,
$$
f_V(v)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)\mathrm du=\mathbf 1_{v\gt0}2\mathrm e^{-2v}\int_0^v\mathrm e^{u}\mathrm du,
$$
that is,
$$
f_V(v)=\mathbf 1_{v\gt0}2\mathrm e^{-2v}(\mathrm e^v-1)=2(\mathrm e^{-v}-\mathrm e^{-2v})\mathbf 1_{v\gt0}.
$$
*Safety check:* The function $f_V$ is nonnegative everywhere and its integral on $\mathbb R$ is $1$.

Comment: hm, so the limits are from 0 to V so that Y=V-U wont be negative?